# Pseudorandom number generator and pseudo-random number sampling

Tags: sampling

I am curious about some glossaries.

1. Does "[pseudorandom number generator (PRNG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)" only mean for
   uniform random number generator? I didn't see one that is not in
   [list of random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators).
2. Does "[Pseudo-random number sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling)" only mean for non-uniform
   random number generator?

   > Pseudo-random number sampling or non-uniform pseudo-random variate
   > generation is the numerical practice of generating pseudo-random
   > numbers that are distributed according to a given probability
   > distribution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RNGs, be it pseudo or quasi, are most often constructed for the Uniform distribution. They can then used for a given distribution via inversion, or better methods.

The Normal distribution is an exception as it is so frequently used, and special algorithm exists (with Box-Muller being a well-known one).

Most statistical computing texts cover this in some detail.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Thanks -- I was actually in a rush to get out the door for work and couldn't fill in more references. Maybe this eve :)

Comment: As I understand it, the Box-Muller method _also_ uses uniform random number generators (in fact, two successive outputs from a PRNG) to create two independent samples from a (standard) normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks! What references were you planning to fill in?

Comment: Well, I have Eubank and Kupresian, "Statistical Computing in C++ and R", 2011, CRC Press on my desk right now which definitely covers this, but so do a few other books as eg the books by Gentle should have something on this, as should the older Statistical Simulation (?) book by Ripley.